# The best way to show lots of images in one .php page

Tags: php, optimization

I want to upload around 1,000 small (let's say 50x50) photos in one .php page. Could I do it without cracking the browser? Maybe there are optimization for images or something like that? How would you do that?

Comment: No user will have the patience to select 1,000 files.

Comment: they can select all. but then if browser fails, you will have to do the same thing over and over. if you use a script. you can manage failed once etc. more control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's theoretically possible, but it's unclear whether browsers will handle it nicely.  I can certainly see it being a pain for users.

You might be better off asking users to upload a single file (like a .zip) containing the images, and let the server unpack it and process the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to put all the filenames into an array, then loop the array with whatever you wanna do with them.

I personally am assuming this is not something for users, but something for you to just let run? Otherwise this would be a really bad idea to implement for your users, might break something...or cause problems on your own server.